# Do I replace the last line 'REPLICATE_API_TOKEN' with my token

Tags: large-language-model, replicate

```
enter code here
```

## get a token: https://replicate.com/account

from getpass import getpass
import os

REPLICATE_API_TOKEN = getpass()
os.environ["REPLICATE_API_TOKEN"] = REPLICATE_API_TOKEN